# Get folder content from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to get data from a folder in a S3 bucket. I have two folders in my bucket, articles and comments. I really only want to get all the data in the comments folder. The data is multiple json files. When I pass

This is an example of a json object in one of the many json files in the comments folder

```
{"7475199770543690800": {"author": "BKD2674", "body": "Saying its Meme, then saying you're buying in lol", "ups": 10, "fullname": "t1_fsqwfto", "created_utc": "2020-06-03T13:54:45", "subreddit": "stocks", "article_id": "gvuau0"}
```

I really only want the "body" portion of the json object since that contains the comment. I would like to store all of the content in the json files in maybe one large dictionary, the iterate through the dictionary and retrieve the contents in the "body" portion of the json object. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('diegos-reddit-bucket')


    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

This is just a sample I typed up to test it. I am getting my bucket, but S3 is reading articles instead of only the comments folder. Also the body variable is of type bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter bucket objects you query for by using the bucket objects [filter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) function (I can't link directly to the function, scroll down a little).

It's true that the object's content is an byte encoded string. You can use `body.decode('utf-8')` to get the textual representation, but `json.load` should be able to handle that for you. Hence, this ought to work

```
import json, boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('diegos-reddit-bucket')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='comments'):
    body = json.load(obj.get()['Body'])
```

There's no way how to read only the `body` section of the JSON file, you have to download it and read it whole first.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I am able to deconstruct the json dictionary into a list and now I have a list of all the comments.

Comment: One extra question. I realized I may run into a memory issue in the future. My lambda function scrapes and puts the data in the S3 bucket every hour. Is there a way to clear the contents in each folder in the S3 bucket at a specific time interval. My plan is to scrape, sentiment analysis, wipe folders, scrape, sentiment analysis, etc.

Comment: I think lifecycle management would work for your case. You can configure your S3 bucket to auto-delete old / expired objects. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html You can also set it programmatically, not just via the web UI.